# Large files not posting, even when post_max_size and upload_max_filesize set to exceed their size in php.ini

Tags: php

I am using PHP Version 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.11.  I use the following code to allow the user to select and upload multiple files.

HTML

```
 <form action="uploadFiles.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple"/></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit[]" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

uploadFiles.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       if ($_FILES["file[]"]["error"] > 0)
       {
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file[]"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            $numFilesUploaded=count($_FILES['file']['name']);
            echo "No. files uploaded : ".$numFilesUploaded."<br><br>";
            for ($inc=0; $inc<$numFilesUploaded; ++$inc){
                echo "File " . $inc . ": " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$inc] . "<br>";
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$inc] . "<br>";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"][$inc] . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$inc] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$inc];
                echo "<br><br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

If the files are small, the posting works fine.  However, if I try to upload two files, each 11.3 MB in size, the post fails.  Inserting

```
print_r($_POST);
```

at the beginning  of uploadFiles.php results in

```
Array ( )
```

(I can upload each of them individually.)  I can understand this being the case with the default php.ini but this is still the case when I edit php.ini and set both upload_max_filesize and post_max_size to 30 MB.  I did a search for every instance of php.ini on my hard drive and made these changes on every one.  I still get an empty array posted to the  php script.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after changing the config files? Does calling `phpinfo()` display the new values?

Comment: What is the value of your `[max-file-uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads)` configuration value... and if you debug `$_FILES`, does it show empty as well?

Comment: @Niels.  Restarting Apache fixed the problem.  Thanks very much!

Comment: @bishop.  Thank you for your suggestion but restarting Apache appears to have fixed the problem.  Thanks,